# How i can get all except "(?i)house\s+(\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?)\b" this?

Tags: .net, regex

With the next regular expression i can get the office or home number of an address street:

```
(?i)house\s+(\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?)\b
```

> SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C AND REST OF ADDRESS

The result is "HOUSE 3 C" and its perfect. 
But now i need to get all except "HOUSE 3 C".
I need to get, for example:

> "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 AND REST OF ADDRESS"

without **"HOUSE 3 C"**.

How can i get this??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single regular expression match must be contiguous; that is, it cannot exclude some section of text in the middle of the match. However, you could simply perform a replacement, like this:

```
var input = "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C AND REST OF ADDRESS";
var pattern = @"(?i)house\s+\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?\b\s*";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
Console.WriteLine(output); // "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 AND REST OF ADDRESS"
```

I added `\s*` to the end of your pattern to swallow up any trailing spaces. Without this, when I joined the result back together, there would have been two spaces between `"808"` and `"AND"`.

---

If you don't want to do that, most regular expression engines allow you to split a string based on whatever matches you find. The result is usually an array (or array-like structure) containing the parts of the string surrounding the match but not including the match itself (unless that option is enabled, depending on the engine you're using).

The easiest solution would be to split the string, then join the results back together.

For example, this will work in JavaScript:

```
var input = "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C AND REST OF ADDRESS";
var output = input.split(/house\s+\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?\b\s*/i).join("");
console.log(output); // "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 AND REST OF ADDRESS"
```

And here is a working example in C#:

```
var input = "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C AND REST OF ADDRESS";
var pattern = @"(?i)house\s+\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?\b\s*";
var output = string.Join("", Regex.Split(input, pattern));
Console.WriteLine(output); // "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 AND REST OF ADDRESS"
```

Notice in both cases, I got rid of the group because it isn't necessary, but I could have also used a non-capturing group, `(?…)`. In either case, this is needed because you in both JavaScript and in .NET, if you have a capturing group within the pattern, the result set will contain the matched group along with the parts that surround the entire pattern.

---

If you don't like that, you could capture the whole string with leading and trailing groups, then concatenate them together:

```
var input = "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C AND REST OF ADDRESS";
var pattern = @"(.*)(?i)house\s+\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?\b\s*(.*)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var output = match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value;
Console.WriteLine(output); // "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 AND REST OF ADDRESS"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could yo be mor expecific? What i do es just what you say. With regular expression split in address field. But after that i have to extract all that was not to split in a field in other field that contain rest of address not relevant. But i dont know how to get this.

Comment: @Patricio I can't do much to identify what's wrong with your code without seeing it. Please show your code and specify what regular expression engine you're using.

Comment: I use .net with my regular expression, but its the same result that http://regex101.com/. So what work in regex101 its fine to me. And the idea is obtain the opuest of (?i)house\s+(\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?)\b. Thanks!

Comment: @Patricio see my updated answer for an example using C# and an explanation of how I changed your code. If this still doesn't solve your issue, please *show your code* by editing the question.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help. But still dont work. I get the same result. Please see this link http://regex101.com/r/uX0vY8 . Here i use your example, but i still get "house 3 c" instead of "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 AND REST OF ADDRESS" (without HOUSE 3 C). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Patricio That doesn't help to understand how you're using the regular expression in your own code. Still, see my updated answer for a few more options.